# Postgresql postmaster takes very long time to start

Tags: postgresql

My situation in Postgres 9.1 is that
I had some running queries which take a lot of memory, then I restarted Postgres immediately. After that I used postmaster to start it again.

/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/postmaster -p 5432 -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data

However, it got stuck for a very long time without starting successfully.

From Postgres documentation, when we restart server immediately, it may prevent postmaster from freeing the system resources (e.g., shared memory and semaphores).
So what should I do now? or just wait for postmaster starting?

Answer (score 0):

Much depends on how you stopped the server.

- If you `kill -9` the `postmaster` process, all the spawned processes (1 for each session) that are using the resources keep on running so your system is still overloaded. Furthermore, the `postmaster` process writes its `pid` to a file very aptly called `postmaster.pid` in the data directory of the cluster (`/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data` in your case). When a file with that name is found, a new `postmaster` process can not start, so you should delete that file. All-in-all, **NEVER** kill the `postmaster`.
- If you used `pg_ctl` or the `rc.d` script to restart the server then you have some other issue on your server. Reboot the server if you can.

In either case, you should not [start the server](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html) by running the `postmaster` manually. Use the `rc.d` script or `pg_ctl` instead.

Lastly, `9.1` is getting old. Consider upgrading to `9.5` which has lots more features.

Comment: does Postgres take a long time for recovery when starting? (using either `rc.d` or `pg_ctl`

Comment: Yes, that is also a possibility. You can check if that is the case in the log file.